# Auto Incrementing User ID number in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying to set up a database of users for an app I'm developing. Each user is specified by an ID number. Right now, I have it set up to auto increment to make things easy. However, I have the ID set as an INT right now. The issue is that the INT data type has a max of 255 fields. That is, I can only have 255 users in the current table.

How can I get around this limit? Or would I need to create a new table each time this 255 limit is reached?

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like `PHPMyAdmin` or `Navicat`, and modify the table and change the field to `INT` or `BIGINT`

NOTE: From your question it feels like that you are actually using `TINYINT` and not INT as the range of `INT` in MySQL is from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` refer to [this post](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) for more information.

Or Alternatly you can run this SQL Query to alter the table directly

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE oldCollumnName newCollumnName INTEGER; // or to any other type you prefer
```

The `oldCollumnName` `newCollumnName` values can be the same but still you need to specify it twice

Documentaion and more information for the above query can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

**Update 1**

As mentioned in the comment by Andriy , to avoid repetition of the column name you can also use the `ALTER... MODIFY` command, the SQL for it will be something like this

```
ALTER TABLE  `tableName` MODIFY  `columnName` INTEGER
```

Comment: I believe you can use the `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY` syntax to avoid repetition of the column name.

Comment: @AndriyM: thanks for mentioning it, updated the answer and included that too in the procedure. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Should work, as the range of int is `-2^31 (-2,147,483,648)` to `2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)`.